# Adding products automatically restrict quantity to 1 in Magento

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have a module that adds a free product to the cart automatically if a product exists.

**The issue:**

1. If the customer keeps shopping and adds other products. The quantity for the free automatic product increases.

**What I need:**

1. I need the quantity of the free automatic product restricted to 1.

**Here's the code:**

```
public function addSubAction($observer) {

$productId = 123;

$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {

  if ($item->getData('product_id') == $productId) {

    $cart     = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $addprod  = 222;
    $qty      = 1;

    $quote  =  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
        ->addProduct( Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($addprod), $qty)
        ->save();
    $cart->save();


  }
}}
```